# How can I make my fonts work in Blackberry device?

Tags: html, css, cordova, fonts, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a phonegap app in Blackberry.

I have some font families. They are:

- Helvetica Neue.ttf
- HelveticaNeueBold_2.ttf
- Siemens Slab Black.ttf
- Siemens Slab Roman.ttf

These fonts are not getting applied in my Blackberry device. But they are applied in desktop browser. How can I make these fonts work in Blackberry device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you embeded them using css? If not, http://bavotasan.com/2010/embedding-fonts-web-site-css-font-face/ . If that doesn't work, check if your version supports css fonts.

Comment: Yes I saw in the Blackberry forums about supported fonts in BB so will use some of them only. Thank you.